# How to find the value in another sheet and return smaller than X?

Tags: excel, vba, find

I have to write a code that will find the city and return the distance smaller than I chose.
For example, in sheet1 cell A2 is a city name, in cell A3 is a distance.
In sheet2 are list of cities and their distance.:
 [image]

I want that in row 1 will find the city (from Sheet1 cell A2) and return only cities, countries and distance which distance values is smaller than value in sheet1 cell A3.

I have try this code but I am not sure what I should do next:

```
Dim Rng_Header As Range: Set Rng_Header = Sheets("Sheet2").[d1:h1]
Dim Ws1 As Worksheet: Set Ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim index_column As Variant
   index_column = Application.Match(Ws1.[a2], Rng_Header, 0)    'find index column in Rng_Header
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Please study the code below. You will have fun. Besides, it also does what you want.

```
Sub ListNearerCities()

    Const Target As String = "D2"           ' place the output there (on Sheet1)

    Dim Fun As Variant                      ' output array
    Dim n As Integer                        ' Fun index counter
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim City As String                      ' Value of A2
    Dim Distance As Long                    ' value of A3
    Dim WsData As Worksheet
    Dim Data As Variant
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim R As Long, C As Long                ' Row / Column

    Set Ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With Ws
        City = .Cells(2, "A").Value
        Distance = .Cells(3, "A").Value
        With .Range(Target).Resize(1, 3)
            ' clear & reset the output area
            .EntireColumn.ClearContents
            With .Offset(-1)
                .Value = Split("City Country Distance")
                .Font.Bold = True
            End With
        End With
    End With

    Set WsData = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    With WsData
        On Error Resume Next
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 4), .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
        C = Application.Match(City, Rng, 0)     'find index column among column captions
        If Err Then
            MsgBox """" & City & """ isn't listed.", _
                   vbInformation, "No data available"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        C = C + 3       ' convert Rng column to Sheet column
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, C).End(xlUp))
        Data = Rng.Value

        ReDim Fun(1 To 3, 1 To UBound(Data))
        For R = 2 To UBound(Data)
            If Distance > Val(Data(R, C)) Then
                If (Val(Data(R, C)) > 0) And (City <> Data(R, 3)) Then
                    n = n + 1
                    Fun(1, n) = Data(R, 1)
                    Fun(2, n) = Data(R, 3)
                    Fun(3, n) = Data(R, C)
                End If
            End If
        Next R
    End With

    If n Then
        ReDim Preserve Fun(1 To 3, 1 To n)
        Ws.Range(Target).Resize(UBound(Fun, 2), UBound(Fun)).Value = Application.Transpose(Fun)
        ' re-use of obsolete string variable
        City = n & " record" & IIf(n = 1, " was", "s were")
    Else
        City = "No data matching the criteria was"
    End If

    MsgBox City & " found.", vbInformation, "Search report"
End Sub
```

Comment: A fine approach+), but think the logic to get **all** city combinations should be refined.
- FYI You might be interested in my approach combining arrays with `FilterXML` results.

Answer (score 0):

**Array approach using `FilterXML` (VBA 2013+)**

This task isn't as trivial as it might seem.

The distance list combines two cities with a distance value in each intersection; positive values are shown here only in the left bottom section to avoid duplicate entries. So instead of `n * n = n²` entries input consists only of `n * (n - 1)/2` positive distances, as `n` zero grey values aren't shown in OP and the right upper half has no (redundant) input.

I completed the list with grey distance values to demonstrate the inherent structure with vertical focus to *Los Angeles*, where the orange values have to be filled by the left horizontal values of Los Angeles being related to Paris and London *(btw forget about actual distances)*:

[image]

This approach combines fast array methods with the possibilities of the WorksheetFunction `FilterXML()`, available in versions 2013+.

```
Sub ExampleCall()
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
'[A]define city & maximum distance
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    With Sheet1
        Dim city     As String: city = .Range("A2").Value
        Dim distance As Long:   distance = .Range("A3").Value
    End With
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
'[B]get results via function getNearest()
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Dim results
    results = getNearest(city, distance)    ' getNearest returns 2-dim results array
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
'[C]write results to target
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    With Sheet1.Range("D2")
        .Resize(1000, 3) = vbNullString
        .Resize(1, 3).Offset(-1) = Array("City", "Country", "Distance")
        .Resize(UBound(results), 3).Value = results
    End With
End Sub
```

**Result example Los Angeles, < 156 km**

[image: Result example]

Note that the programatically added Paris distance in the vertical data column for Los Angeles is valid due to the set condition, the second empty distance of exactly 156 to London is lower than 156 km and thus omitted.

**Help functions**

- `getNearest()` to structure the essential processing steps
- `getData()` to get all needed data (providing for a wellformed xml string) and
- `xCities()` demonstrating the use of `FilterXML()`

```
Function getNearest(city, distance) As Variant()

Const COLOFFSET = 3
With Sheet2
'[0]get last row in column A:A
    Dim n: n = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'[1]get base references (moving due to current city number)
    Dim horizontal As Range: Set horizontal = .Range("1:1").Resize(1, n - 1).Offset(columnoffset:=COLOFFSET)
    Dim vertical   As Range: Set vertical = .Range("C2:C" & n)
End With

'[2]get cities
    Dim cities: cities = Application.Transpose(vertical.Offset(0, -2).Value)
    ReDim Preserve cities(0 To UBound(cities) - 1)

'[3]get current city number (ordinal, i.e. 1-based)
    Dim curr: curr = Application.Match(city, cities, 0)
    If IsError(curr) Then curr = 10000    ' provide for not found

'[4]get data prepared for XML filtering and pass them to xCities using FilterXML function
    Dim data: data = getData(cities, curr, horizontal, vertical)

'[5]return function results
    getNearest = xCities(data, distance)     ' << return results

End Function
```

```
Function getData(cities, ByVal curr As Long, horizontal As Range, vertical As Range) As Variant()
With horizontal.Parent
'[1]get current data
    Dim ctry: ctry = Application.Transpose(vertical)
    Dim v:    v = Application.Transpose(vertical.Offset(columnoffset:=curr).Value)
    Dim h:    h = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(horizontal.Offset(rowoffset:=curr).Value))
    Debug.Print Join(h, "|")
'[2]reorg v to get
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(v)
        ' complete zero data at column top
        If Val(v(i)) <= 0 Then v(i) = h(i)
        ' add some node formatting
        v(i) = "<c ctry='" & ctry(i) & _
               "' km='" & v(i) & "'>" & _
               cities(i - 1) & "</c>"
    Next i
End With
getData = v
End Function
```

```
Function xCities(v, ByVal distance As Long)
'Purpose: return 2-dim array with integrated FilterXML results

'create wellformed XML string out of passed array data
Dim myXML As String: myXML = "<cities>" & Join(v) & "</cities>"
Debug.Print myXML
Dim myXPath As String: myXPath = "//c[@km>0][@km<" & distance & "]"

On Error Resume Next
Dim results
results = WorksheetFunction.FilterXML(myXML, myXPath)

If Err.Number Then
    MsgBox "nothing found"
    xCities = Array(Array(Empty), Array(Empty))
Else
    Dim results2
    results2 = WorksheetFunction.FilterXML(myXML, myXPath & "/@ctry")
    Dim results3
    results3 = WorksheetFunction.FilterXML(myXML, myXPath & "/@km")
    'provide for single findings - only 1 city (<< Edit as of 2020-04-03)
    If TypeName(results) = "String" Then
         ReDim tmp(1 To 1, 1 To 3)
         tmp(1, 1) = results: tmp(1, 2) = results2: tmp(1, 3) = results3
         xCities = tmp
    Else                    ' several cities found
        ReDim Preserve results(1 To UBound(results), 1 To 3)
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To UBound(results)
            results(i, 2) = results2(i, 1)
            results(i, 3) = results3(i, 1)
        Next i
        xCities = Application.Index(results, Evaluate("row(1:" & UBound(results) & ")"), Array(1, 2, 3))
    End If

End If
End Function
```

**Further hint**

The well formed XML string for *Los Angeles* would look as follows:
The `FilterXML()` function needs an `XPath` expression to get the valid nodes.
Note the `@` prefix when referencing attributes such as `km` or `ctry` within the `<c>` nodes. The `[]` brackets indicate the relevant condition, a double slash `//` indicates a search a any hierarchy level, so that you need not refer to the *DocumentElement* of `<cities>...</cities>`

```
<cities>
    <c ctry='France' km='38'>Paris</c>
    <c ctry='UK' km='156'>London</c>
    <c ctry='USA' km='0'>Los Angeles</c> 
    <c ctry='Italy' km='218'>Roma</c> 
    <c ctry='Italy' km='88'>Milan</c> 
    <c ctry='France' km='112'>Nica</c> 
    <c ctry='Ireland' km='68'>Dublin</c>
</cities>
```

Comment: I took your hint and spent 30 minutes learning about XPATH syntax. https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp