# VBA: completing a matrix

Tags: excel, vba, function, matrix, user-defined-functions

I have a 3 by 3 matrix, where elements (1,1), (2,1), (2,2), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3) are given:

```
X   .   .
X   X   .
X   X   X
```

I need to write a program that writes out the missing elements, where (1,2)=(2,1), (1,3)=(3,1) and (2,3)=(3,2). I have written the following code:

```vb
Function kiegeszito(a)
    For i = 1 To 3
        For j = 1 To 3
            If i < j Then
                a(i, j) = a(j, i)
            Else        
                a(i, j) = a(i, j)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    kiegeszito = a
End Function
```

However, this does not seem to work, could anybody help me why is this not working?

Comment: They are all great answers but IMHO missing the point that the reason for not working is just that you need to change the first line of the function to Sub kiegeszito(ByRef a As Variant) last line to End Sub and take out kiegeszito = a. The actual code (though maybe not the most efficient) is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the `Else` condition:

```
Function kiegeszito(a)
    For i = 1 To 3
        For j = 1 To 3
            If i < j Then a(i, j) = a(j, i)
        Next j
    Next i

    kiegeszito = a
End Function
```

Answer (score 4):

**Get twin data in 2-dim matrix avoiding extra `n*(n-1)/2` condition checks**

The following approach

- reduces the number of unnecessary condition checks by incrementing the 2nd loop starts
- accepts any wanted base of 2-dim data:

```
Sub CompleteMatrix(ByRef data)
'count row|=column elements
Dim cnt As Long: cnt = UBound(data) - LBound(data) + 1

'fill missing twin data (identified by inverted indices)
Dim i As Long, j As Long
For i = LBound(data) To cnt - 1
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'next column starts from incremented row index
    '(thus avoiding n*(n-1)/2 IF-conditions)
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    For j = i + 1 To UBound(data, 2)
        data(i, j) = data(j, i)     ' assign twin data
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

An example call creating e.g. a 1-based 2-dim datafield array might be

```
Sub ExampleCall()
    Dim v: v = Tabelle3.Range("A1:C3").Value
    CompleteMatrix v
End Sub
```

**Further link**

A practical example using such a *mirrored array* might be a distance array; a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60944470/how-to-find-the-value-in-another-sheet-and-return-smaller-than-x/61000335#61000335) demonstrates how to apply the `FilterXML()` function thereon.

Answer (score 1):

### Fill Array

- Using a method (`fillArray`) you could modify the array 'in place':

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub fillArrayTEST()
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = Range("A1:C3").Value
    debugPrint2D Data
    fillArray Data
    debugPrint2D Data
End Sub

Sub fillArray(ByRef Data As Variant)
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = UBound(Data, 2)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        For j = 1 To cCount
            If i < j Then Data(i, j) = Data(j, i)
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub

Sub debugPrint2D(ByVal Data As Variant)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = LBound(Data, 1) To UBound(Data, 1)
        For j = LBound(Data, 2) To UBound(Data, 2)
            Debug.Print "[" & i & "," & j & "]", Data(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

**A Homage to T.M.'s Brilliant Solution**

```
Sub completeMatrix(ByRef Data As Variant)
    Dim rLower As Long: rLower = LBound(Data, 1)
    Dim cLower As Long: cLower = LBound(Data, 2)
    Dim iDiff As Long: iDiff = cLower - rLower
    Dim cStart As Long: cStart = iDiff + 1
    Dim cUpper As Long: cUpper = UBound(Data, 2)
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    For r = rLower To UBound(Data, 1) - rLower
        For c = cStart + r To cUpper
            Data(r, c) = Data(c - iDiff, r + iDiff)
        Next c
    Next r
End Sub

Sub completeMatrixTEST()
    Dim Data As Variant: ReDim Data(0 To 2, 2 To 4)
    Data(0, 2) = 1
    Data(1, 2) = 2
    Data(1, 3) = 3
    Data(2, 2) = 4
    Data(2, 3) = 5
    Data(2, 4) = 6
    debugPrint2D Data
    completeMatrix Data
    'Range("G1").Resize(UBound(Data, 1) - LBound(Data, 1) + 1, _
        UBound(Data, 2) - LBound(Data, 2) + 1).Value = Data
    Debug.Print
    debugPrint2D Data
End Sub
```